# PGraphics and Minim don't work well together?

Tags: processing, minim, pgraphics

I had recently coded some sketches and am now currently trying to change these into classes using also PGraphics as data type so I can pass the actual graphics created into Resolume, through Syphon [this needs the graphics to be in PGraphic data].

When I'm trying to do this, the audio reactivity created using the minim library is changing drastically, hence changing the visuals and making them less reactive. It is like PGraphics and minim are kind of conflicting with each other.

I am working with Processing 3.0a3. I also tried the code in the latest Processing 2, same problem.

I am putting links of the pde files so you can see whats going on exactly:

[**The graphics created through a class**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1UFlbqCszEVV1NpOVRlblJuMWM/edit?usp=sharing)

[**The sketch without the class**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1UFlbqCszEVTU51d1dSamhmbVE/edit?usp=sharing)

I hope someone can figure out what is going on here. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hey guys I managed to find the problem with the help of the Processing Forum. I was calling the functions begin/endShape() where I should have been calling begin/endDraw();

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys I managed to find the problem with the help of the Processing Forum. I was calling the functions begin/endShape() where I should have been calling begin/endDraw();